# How can I compute the time complexity of this code?

Tags: runtime, time-complexity

```
def long_common_prefix(input_list):


    for i in range(1, len(input_list)):
        input_list[0] = get_prefix(input_list[0], input_list[i])

    return input_list[0]

def get_prefix(s1, s2):

    p1 = p2 = 0
    e1, e2 = len(s1), len(s2)
    currLongest = ''
    while p1 != e1 and p2 != e2:
        if s1[p1] == s2[p2]:
            currLongest += s1[p1]
            p1 += 1
            p2 += 1
        else:
            break

    return currLongest
```

This is a code that computes the longest common prefix of strings in a list. So, for example, `['abcd','abc','ab']` would give me `'ab'`. The code works well, but I wasn't sure how to define the time and space complexity of the code.

In `long_common_prefix`, there is only a single loop which is `O(N)`, and inside the loop, it calls the helper `get_prefix`. Since the `get_prefix` would be `O(N)` and it will be running inside the single loop, would it be `O(N^2)` where N is the length of the string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, except `N` is the length of the input list, but `get_prefix` operates in linear time (and space) on the strings, and the lengths of the strings is in no way related to the length of the input list.

The complexity of `get_prefix` is `O(M)`, where `M` is the length of the common prefix.

Time complexity: `O(N*M)`
Space complexity: `O(M)`